# Linear algebra: Prove the sum of two spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question:

Suppose $S=\text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ and $T=\text{Span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_q\}$. Show that $S+T=\text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n,v_1,\ldots,v_q\}$. Can anyone provide some tips?

Approach: Show any vector in $S+T$ can be written as a linear combination of ${u_1,\dots,u_n,v_1,\dots,v_q}$ and
The span of ${u_1,\dots,u_n,v_1,\dots,v_q}$ is contained in $S+T$.

Edit:

My attempt:

Let s be in Span S, then s can be written in a linear combination of Span S: $s=\text u_1a_1 + u_2a_2 + \dots + u_na_n  $

Let t be in Span S, then s can be written in a linear combination of Span S: $t=\text v_1b_1 + v_2b_2 + \dots + v_qb_q  $

$s+t= \text u_1a_1 + u_2a_2 + \dots + u_na_n + v_1b_1 + v_2b_2 + \dots + v_qb_q  $

As $\text u_1a_1 + u_2a_2 + \dots + u_na_n + v_1b_1 + v_2b_2 + \dots + v_qb_q $ is in Span S+T and s is in Span S and t is in Span T, so $S+T=\text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n,v_1,\ldots,v_q\}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Well, how does a general element in $S+T$ looks like? What can you say about it?

Comment: Please include the definition of Span in the question. (This instruction is also a hint).

Comment: Okay! Let me try it by myself first.

Comment: For clarity, you should start your discussion by defining $S+T$.

Answer (score 0):

I personally am not convinced by your argument, or at least it is missing some details. Here is how I would do it.

Proof approach (same as OP's): $\ 1.\ $ Show that $S+T\subset \text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n,v_1,\ldots,v_q\}\quad 2.\ $ Show that $ \text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n,v_1,\ldots,v_q\}\subset S+T.$
$$$$
$1)\ $ Let $w\in S+T.$ Then $\exists\ s\in S,\ t\in T\ $ such that $w=s+t.$ Since $s\in S:= \text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\},\ \exists\ \lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n,\ $all in $\ \mathbb{F},\ $  such that $\ s = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i u_i. \ $
Similarly, since $t\in T:= \text{Span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\},\ \exists\ \mu_1,\ldots, \mu_n,\ $all in $\ \mathbb{F},\ $  such that $\ t = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i v_i.\ $ Therefore, $\ w = s+t = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i u_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i v_i \in \text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n,v_1,\ldots,v_q\}.\ $ This shows that $S+T\subset \text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n,v_1,\ldots,v_q\}$.

$$$$

$2)\ $ Let $\ w\in \text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n,v_1,\ldots,v_q\}.\ $ Then $\ \exists\ \lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n,\ \mu_1,\ldots, \mu_n,\ $ all in $\ \mathbb{F},\ $ such that $\ w = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i u_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i v_i.\ $ Now, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i u_i \in \text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\} = S,\ $ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i v_i \in \text{Span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\} = T.\ $ Since by definition, $a\in S,\ b\in T \implies a+b \in S+T,\ $ it follows that $\ w = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i u_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i v_i \in S + T.\ $ This shows that $ \text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n,v_1,\ldots,v_q\}\subset S+T.$

This concludes the proof.

These two parts, $1)$ and $2),$ can probably be made into one big part with just $\iff$'s. But here I do not wish to sacrifice clarity for brevity. However, in an exam, the following proof will be quicker to write (if you are someone who "memorises" proofs):

$$w\in S+T$$

$$ \iff \exists\ s\in S,\ t\in T\ \text{ such that } w=s+t $$

$$ \iff \exists\ \lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n,\  \mu_1,\ldots, \mu_n,\  \text{ all in } \mathbb{F},\ \text{ such that } w = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i u_i +  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i v_i, \text{ which equals } s+t \text{ for some } s\in S,\ t\in T$$

$$ \iff w \in \text{Span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_n,v_1,\ldots,v_q\}. $$